# How to make Windows 8.1 app go to a visual state?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-store-apps

I try to retarget my app from Windows 8 to Windows 8.1. From old version XAML markup is left.

```
<VisualStateGroup x:Name="ApplicationViewStates">
    <VisualState x:Name="FullScreenLandscape">...</VisualState>
    <VisualState x:Name="Filled">...</VisualState>
    <VisualState x:Name="FullScreenPortrait">...</VisualState>
    <VisualState x:Name="Snapped">...</VisualState>
</VisualStateGroup>
```

How to make app go to one state when certain window width is reached? For example, how to activate "Snapped" visual state, when window width is 800 px or smaller. Is it possible to do that without editing XAML code for this states?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [VisualStateManager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.visualstatemanager.gotostate%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) class:

```
VisualStateManager.GoToState(yourcontrolinstance, "FullScreenLandscape", true);
```